# как присвоить datetime другой год? python

Tags: python, datetime

У меня есть объекты datetime, например datetime(1998-11-12), datetime(2020-01-31), datetime(2013-08-25) и мне нужно всем объектам, где год равен 2020, обновить это значение до единицы (не трогая остальные). Я пробовал

```
bdate.year = 1
```

так же я пробовал

```
DATE = datetime(1, 1, 1)
bdate.year = DATE.year
```

но всё это выдаёт ошибку. Как мне обновить год в datetime?

Comment: Зачем вам нужен 1 год от РХ? Может вам в данном случае нужно timedelta вместо datetime? Опишите подробнее что вы хотите получить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```
import datetime

date = datetime.date(2020, 1, 31)
print(date)

date = date.replace(year=1)
print(date)
```